# Group categories with only one object with a defined product

Tags: group-theory, category-theory

Do you know how to deal with this kind of problem?

> Let $G$ be a group and $\mathcal {G} $ be the category with one object $G$ and $\mbox {Mor}( {G} ; {G} ) = {G} $.
>   Find all groups $G$ such that the product in $\mathcal {G}$ is defined.

Comment: What do you mean by $\mbox {Mor}(\mathcal {G} ; \mathcal {G} ) = \mathcal {G}$? Oh, it seems this is edited and maybe it should be $\mbox {Mor}(G ; G) = \mathcal {G}$ or $… = G$ or something. It still doesn’t make sense to me: What do you want to say here?

Comment: Yeah it was edited it should be Mor(G;G) = G, i.e. the morphism is "elements of group G"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume that the question should look like this:

> Let $G$ be a group and $\mathcal{G}$ be the category with one object $\star$ with $\operatorname{Mor}(\star, \star ) = G$ (as monoids).  Find all groups $G$ such that the cartesian product is defined in $\mathcal {G}$.

In this case, if $\star\times\star$ exists, then we must have $\star\times\star = \star$, and $\operatorname{Mor}(\star, \star )=\operatorname{Mor}(\star\times\star, \star ) = \operatorname{Mor}(\star, \star )\times \operatorname{Mor}(\star, \star )$, where the identification is via two projection maps $\pi_1,\pi_2\in G$.

In other words, the map $g\mapsto (\pi_1 g, \pi_2 g)$ must be an isomorphism $G\to G\times G$.  But then, for any $(a,b)\in G\times G$, we have $ab^{-1} = \pi_1 \pi_2^{-1}$, which can only occur if $G$ is the trivial group.

I could be wrong about how to interpret the question, but if so, a lot of clarification is in order.

Comment: Could you explain it in more detail? How would solution look like if instead of * we took G? Why * x * = *? How does this second part of an explanation happened? I am new to the category theory and algebra, so my question could be silly :)

Comment: Well, I'm clearly just using "$\star$" as a meaningless placeholder.  It just means "the single object of $\mathcal{G}$".  We could call it "$G$" instead, but I think this would just lead to confusion without really gaining us anything—when we identify a group with a one-element category, we are identifying the elements of the group with the morphisms, and further identifying the set of elements with the source and target of those morphisms seems needlessly confusing to me.

Comment: I say that $\star \times \star = \star$ because that's the only thing it could be!  $\mathcal{G}$ has only one object, so if the object $\star\times \star$ exists, it had better just be $\star$ again.  But the universal property of the cartesian product means that, if we want the product $A_1\times A_2$, we want more than just an element, we want an element with two projection morphisms $\pi_1:A_1\times A_2 \to A_1$ and  $\pi_2:A_1\times A_2 \to A_2$.  But here, all our objects are $\star$, and all our morphisms are elements of $G$, so we can interpret this all in terms of group theory.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You're explanations were very useful.

Comment: You are most welcome.  I'm very entertained by this sort of question.